# Microsoft SQL Server Scaling for multi-billion row table

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

Calling all MSSQL server gurus!
I'm currently working on a project that involves a table with the following layout:

[DbNodeClosures]

- [Id]       BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
- [ParentID] BIGINT NOT NULL,
- [ChildID]  BIGINT NOT NULL,
- [Depth]    INT NOT NULL

This is a closure table used for storing parent child relationships and currently has the following indexes:

[IX_DbNodeClosures_ParentID] ON [dbo].[DbNodeClosures] ([ParentID])

[IX_DbNodeClosures_ChildID] ON [dbo].[DbNodeClosures] ([ChildID]) INCLUDE ([Depth], [ParentID])

[IX_DbNodeClosures_ParentID-ChildID] ON [dbo].[DbNodeClosures] ([ParentID], [ChildID]) INCLUDE ([Depth])

Queries to this table typically involve querying all children ID's using the parentID or vice versa.  Rows in this table are only inserted or removed, never updated.  We currently have this working and with 600 million rows, performance is still excellent, however we are about to enter a migration period where that number will exceed 1.2 billion rows, and as time goes on, potentially grow to 30+ billion rows.  At 600 million rows, the current table including indexes takes about 30 GB of storage on our SQL server.

So now the real questions:

How well will this scale?

Will query performance degrade as the number of rows increase?

Will insert and delete performance slow significantly as the number of rows increase?

I have been researching options like Table partitioning (available on all versions of MSSQL server 2016+) and ColumnStore Indexes, but don't have any real world experience with them nor do I have real-world experience with scaling a MSSQL table to billions of rows. (And yes we are looking at a wholesale changeover to NOSQL for it's scaling benefits, but that will be prohibitively expensive from a development cost stand-point) I have seen that others (NASDAQ) are able to get Quintillions of rows, so I think it's possible and I'm hoping someone who does have experience in this area can offer some insight as to what they've seen as far as performance and scaling of SQL server at these levels.
Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: This is an interesting and important topic but not suited to SO. This site is for specific programming questions. I would be very reluctant to start making changes to a system for a performance problem that doesn't exist. Load all this data in a test environment and see how the current architecture scales. You might just surprise yourself.

Comment: Thank you Sean, I also included this on the Database Administrators site, but it was immediately closed for being too broad, and the 600 million rows is actually test data, the production environment is closer to 26 million, so performance is pretty good, I was just hoping someone with experience could share at what point performance takes a hit strictly from volume regardless of indexes.  I'm worried about a ceiling...

Comment: There isn't a magical number where things start to slow down. It is far more complex than that. So many things affect performance, volume of data in the table is just one piece of the puzzle.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a possible application for a [SQL Graph Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture)

FWIW we have much wider tables with billions of rows in one of our production systems and things run pretty well.

Comment: Thank you, that was extremely useful, especially that you have wider tables with billions of rows, are you doing anything  special from a hardware standpoint?  (multiple drives, partitioning, etc?)

Comment: Our tables are partitioned monthly with each partition on a separate filegroup

Comment: Thank you again for your response, do you know if it's partitioned to accelerate reads/writes, or for storage purposes?